# -bash: /mnt/c/Program Files/nodejs/npm: /bin/sh^M: bad interpreter: No such file or directoryが出現したときに、改行コードを確認する方法を知りたいです

Tags: bash, vue.js, npm, wsl

**現象**
WSL2のUbuntuのbashで`npm install vue`を実行したときに、`-bash: /mnt/c/Program Files/nodejs/npm: /bin/sh^M: bad interpreter: No such file or directory`が出現する

そこで、`cat -e /bin/sh`コマンドを使って、改行コードを確認しようとすると、出力された物が全て文字化けしてしまっている

**期待値**
`cat -e /bin/sh`コマンドを使って、改行コードを確認したい

**再現手順**

1. node.jsをインストールする
2. npmをインストールする
3. `npm install vue`を実行する
4. すると、`-bash: /mnt/c/Program Files/nodejs/npm: /bin/sh^M: bad interpreter: No such file or directory`が出現する
5. 改行コードを調べるために、`cat -e /bin/sh`を実行する

**参考リンク**
[/bin/bash^M: bad interpreter: そのようなファイルやディレクトリはありません (No such file or directory)](https://totech.hateblo.jp/entry/2014/03/19/174129)

Comment: WSL を使っているのに Windows 側の npm を参照しているのがまずおかしい気がしますし、改行コードと文字コード (に起因する文字化け) は別の話です。エラーメッセージに `^M` と出ているので不要な改行コードが含まれているのは既に確認できているのではないでしょうか？

Comment: この辺かな？[WSL上で、Windowsのnpmを使ってしまう](https://qiita.com/RikuS3n/items/c0dbf5151af2250c311f) … npmがシェルスクリプトなら, `cat -e (対象ディレクトリーの)/nodejs/npm` として確認するとよいです。`/bin/sh` は言語本体なのでバイナリが表示されるはず。参考: [shebang](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%82%B7%E3%83%90%E3%83%B3_(Unix))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

なんか限りなく XY 問題な気がしますが

> `cat -e /bin/sh` コマンドを使って、改行コードを確認したい

あなたが確認したいのは `/mnt/c/Program Files/nodejs/npm` の改行コードであって `/bin/sh` の改行コードではないはず。

> 文字化け

そりゃバイナリファイルである `/bin/sh` をコンソールに表示すれば化けているに決まっています。

`/bin/sh^M: bad interpreter` のメッセージはシェルスクリプトファイルの１行目 `shebang` (シバンともシェバンとも) の改行コードが `CR LF` かつ、そのシバンを解釈する何か ( [execve](https://linuxjm.osdn.jp/html/LDP_man-pages/man2/execve.2.html) カーネル関数と `/bin/sh` の合わせ技なんだけど) が LF 改行のみ対応の場合に `#!/bin/sh<CR><LF>` のシバン行を `/bin/sh<CR>` なファイルを起動すると解釈し、そんなファイルはないのでエラーになるという現象です。なのであなたのところで発生したそのエラーメッセージの原因は `/mnt/c/Program Files/nodejs/npm` のシバン行の改行コードが `CR LF` であることです。 `/bin/sh` 側ではありません。

なので使うツールも確認する対象ファイルも違うっス。こういう場合は普通 `file` なり `od` なりで確認すればいいです。ウチの WSL2 Ubuntu 20.04 TLS の場合

```
$ file /bin/sh /bin/dash abc.sh
/bin/sh:   symbolic link to dash
/bin/dash: ELF 64-bit LSB shared object, x86-64, <以下略>
abc.sh:    POSIX shell script, ASCII text executable, with CRLF terminators
$ od -tx1 abc.sh
0000000 23 21 2f 62 69 6e 2f 73 68 0d 0a 65 63 68 6f 20
0000020 61 62 63 0d 0a
0000025
$ ./abc.sh
abc
$
```

ってことで追及すべきはなぜ `npm` コマンドの内部改行コードが `CR LF` なのか、だけどその辺は別途コメントにある通りなのだろうと思われます。

---

まあシバン評価するルーチン（ [linux](/questions/tagged/linux) kernel ですね）側が改行コード `CR LF` に対応してくれていればいいだけですし、オイラんところの Ubuntu 20.04 TLS ストア更新日 2021/06/12 では前述のとおりシバン行の改行が `CR LF` である `abc.sh` も期待通り動いているわけで、質問者さんもストアアプリの更新で WSL2 Ubuntu を更新すればそのまま動くかもしれないです。